# dynamically loaded items not turning to owl Carousel in modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, owl-carousel

Loading divs of images with on click, but items wont turn into Owl Carousel. What is wrong with my code? 
here is the [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ns9kv9oj/1/)

**click on:**

```
<a href="#modal-work01" data-toggle="modal" data-qty="10" data-srs="work02-">
```

**div items gets loaded in:**

```
<div id="owl-work-modal01" class="owl-carousel">
```

**My scripts:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.thumb a').on('click',function()
    {
        $('#owl-work-modal01').empty();
        let qty = $(this).data('qty');
        let srs = $(this).attr('data-srs');
        for (var i = 0; i < qty; i++) {
        $('#owl-work-modal01').append('<div class="item"><figure><img src="images/'+srs+i+'.jpg" alt=""></figure></div>');
        }
        $(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel();
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: what do you mean for **click on:**? are you using boostrap?

Comment: Create a working example, otherwise it's hard to help

Comment: @gaetanoM Click on <a> to run my script. then that script, first, will load 10 children to **#owl-work-modal01** , then, will run $(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel();

Comment: @Dekel just added the JsFiddle

Comment: better then the fact that you got a solution I hope that you learned that when providing a working example it is much easier for others to help :)

Comment: @Dekel I know,and I still don't know how would you possibly know the solution, but it fixed the issue :)

Comment: The thing is that when you use `owlCarousel` - it actually change the DOM and based on the structure you have, and it register listeners based on the number of elements you currently have in your container. If the element changed - you must reset everything...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `destroy` the `owlCarousel` before adding new images and init it:

```
  $("#owl-example").data('owlCarousel').destroy()
```

Check the following snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#owl-example").owlCarousel({
        autoPlay: 1000,
        margine: 10,
        slideSpeed: 200,
        paginationSpeed: 600,
        rewindSpeed: 800,
        stopOnHover: true,
        navigation: true,
        pagination: true,
        singleItem: true,
        autoHeight: true,
    });

    $('#clickMe').on('click', function() {
        $("#owl-example").data('owlCarousel').destroy()
        $('#owl-example').empty();
        //name of images and quantity
        let qty = 5;
        //append images to modal
        for (var i = 0; i < qty; i++) {
            $('#owl-example').append('<div class="item"><figure><img src="http://rubinmuseum.org/images/content/nepal_artworks2_500.jpg" alt=""></figure></div>');
        }
        $("#owl-example").owlCarousel({
            autoPlay: 1000,
            margine: 10,
            slideSpeed: 200,
            paginationSpeed: 600,
            rewindSpeed: 800,
            stopOnHover: true,
            navigation: true,
            pagination: true,
            singleItem: true,
            autoHeight: true,
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.transitions.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.theme.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.carousel.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.carousel.js"></script>
<a id="clickMe" style="cursor: pointer">click here to see the issue</a>
<div id="owl-example" class="owl-carousel">
  <div class="item">
    <figure>
      <img src="https://www.artmajeur.com/medias/home/a/d/administrator/home/num_9307189.jpg" alt="">
    </figure>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <figure>
      <img src="https://www.artmajeur.com/medias/home/a/d/administrator/home/num_9307189.jpg" alt="">
    </figure>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <figure>
     <img src="https://www.artmajeur.com/medias/home/a/d/administrator/home/num_9307189.jpg" alt="">
    </figure>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice and easy solution and worked perfectly for me!